# Limiting syscall access for a Linux application

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, hook, system-calls

Assume a Linux binary `foobar` which has two different modes of operation:

- Mode A: A well-behaved mode in which syscalls `a`, `b` and `c` are used.
- Mode B: A things-gone-wrong mode in which syscalls `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are used.

Syscalls `a`, `b` and `c` are harmless, whereas syscall `d` is potentially dangerous and could cause instability to the machine.

Assume further that which of the two modes the application runs is random: the application runs in mode A with probability 95 % and in mode B with probability 5 %. The application comes without source code so it cannot be modified, only run as-is.

I want to make sure that the application cannot execute syscall `d`. When executing syscall `d` the result should be either a NOOP or an immediate termination of the application.

How do I achieve that in a Linux environment?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify the meaning of "probability" in your question in case there is something to misunderstand there?

Comment: Pascal: Sure! Post edited with a clarification. For the purpose of this questions the "mode choice" is random.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is the application linked statically?

If not, you may override some symbols, for example, let's redefine `socket`:

```
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
        write(1,"Error\n",6);
        return -1;
}
```

Then build a shared library:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared test.c -o libtest.so
```

Let's run:

```
nc -l -p 6000
```

Ok.

And now:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so nc -l -p 6000
Error
Can't get socket
```

What happens when you run with variable `LD_PRELOAD=./libtest.so`? It overrides with symbols defined in libtest.so over those defined in the C library.

Comment: This actually does not fulfil the security requirements?  It is fairly easy to get code to load an appropriate syscall number in `eax` or whatever the CPU conventions is and then transfer control to the tail end of 'a', 'b', or 'c' syscalls.  Altering a syscall table per process and loader changes (like SELinux) are the only way to stop user space corruption.  See for instance [ROP at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming).  At least this answer assumes several things in the system are beyond compromise.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that [systrace](http://www.provos.org/index.php?/categories/2-Systrace) does exactly what you need. From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systrace):

> An application is allowed to make only those system calls specified as permitted in the policy. If the application attempts to execute a system call that is not explicitly permitted an alarm gets raised.

Answer (score 5):

This is one possible application of [sandboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) (specifically, Rule-based Execution). One popular implementation is [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux).

You will have to [write the policy](https://web.archive.org/web/20170326131853/http://www.lurking-grue.org/writingselinuxpolicyHOWTO.html) that corresponds to what you want to allow the process to do.

Comment: This is certainly the use case for SELinux. Other sandboxing technologies are available.

Comment: @stsquad I incorporated your comment. You were perhaps reacting partly to the "claims" in the previous version… I phrased it this way because of having heard some people SELinux is not so usable in practice, precisely because of the need for adequate policies. Not having tried it, I do not have an opinion one way or the other, so perhaps the new version is better from this point of view.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what [seccomp-bpf](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/prctl/seccomp_filter.txt) is for. See an [example how to restrict access to syscalls](https://blog.jtlebi.fr/2014/05/29/introduction-to-seccomp-bpf-linux-syscall-filter/).